# SQL Server oddity with full-text indexing and case sensitivity and numbers

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case-sensitive, stop-words, full-text-indexing

This problem may be unique to our server, but I can't tell from the symptoms where the issue may lie.

I have a field (searchtitle) in a table (fsItems) that has a full-text index turned ON. For the record with primary key (IDItem) 704629 the content of this field is "TEST AFA 0 TEST".

Surprisingly, the following query returns no results:

`SELECT * FROM fsItems WHERE CONTAINS(searchtitle,'AFA') AND IDItem = 704629`

However, if I change the content to be "TEST afa 0 TEST" or "TEST AFA O TEST" (capital "O" instead of zero) the query returns the record. (It also returns the record if I change the content to "TEST AFB 0 TEST" and the CONTAINS argument to 'AFB'.)

At first I thought maybe AFA was some kind of stop word, but that wouldn't explain why changing zero to upper-case "O" returns the proper result.

Any idea what is going on here?

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: I suggest you ask this question at https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Check that you word is not part of the stop list `select * from sys.fulltext_system_stopwords`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very interesting little quirk. It appears SQL Server is considering "AFA 0" as a single "word". My guess is this is an issue with the word breakers configured for standard English. It appears you can manually adjust them, but it doesn't look simple or intuitive. See Microsoft's how to documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/view-or-change-registered-filters-and-word-breakers?view=sql-server-ver15)

### Identifying Words in Full-text Index

The below script lists every word in a full text index. If you run this against your table, you'll see in column **display_term** word "AFA 0". Side note: this script is also very useful in optimizing full text indexes by identifying "noisy" words to add to your stop list

```
Select *
From sys.dm_fts_index_keywords(Db_Id(),Object_Id('dbo.tbl_fulltext_test') /*Replace with your table name*/)
Order By document_count Desc
```

### Full SQL Used to Identify the Issue

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_fulltext_test
(ID int constraint PK_fulltext_test primary key identity (1,1) 
,String Varchar(1000)
)

Create Fulltext Catalog ct_test
With Accent_Sensitivity = Off

Create Fulltext Stoplist sl_test
From System Stoplist;

Create Fulltext Index On tbl_fulltext_test(String)
Key Index PK_fulltext_test On ct_test
With Stoplist = sl_test,Change_Tracking Auto;


INSERT INTO tbl_fulltext_test
VALUES 
 ('TEST AFA 0 TEST') /*Zero*/
,('TEST afa 0 TEST') /*Zero*/
,('TEST AFB 0 TEST') /*AFB*/
,('TEST AFA O TEST') /*Letter O*/

/*Returns rows 2 and 4*/
SELECT *
FROM tbl_fulltext_test
WHERE CONTAINS (String,'AFA')

/*Returns row 1*/
SELECT *
FROM tbl_fulltext_test
WHERE CONTAINS (String,'"AFA 0"')
```

Comment: Wow, fascinating. I'm choosing your answer because it has given me real insight into what is going on, although it doesn't "really" make sense. Thank you for this effort! Btw, I discovered all my problems seemed to go away if I replaced all the values in the indexed field with their LOWER() equivalents. For me, since these values are ONLY used for retrieving records and their actual values are never displayed, this helps. Normally, of course, that wouldn't be a practical solution. You gotta love Microsoft.